# a surface tangent to a plane along a curve

Tags: differential-geometry

I can't visualize how a surface is tangent to a plane along a curve. Tangent plane of a surface at a specific point intersect the surface at only one point, doesn't it ? Can someone help me to visualize by a figure or giving a detail explanation ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one example: Take a right-circular cylinder. A tangent plane at any point on the surface of the cylinder will intersect the surface in a straight line parallel to the axis of the cylinder and not just at one point (The cylinder is, in fact, a ruled surface).

Comment: Oh, I see now. Is it possible for only ruled surfaces ?

Comment: @diffgeo I am struggling to think of an example which is not a ruled surface, but can't supply a proof.

Comment: Yeah, I am newbie :) Thanks for the example, it was helpful.